# Radius of Convergence of a Matrix Power Series

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, power-series

I am trying to figure out the conditions for a matrix, for the analytic matrix function to converge. For example,

$$e^{A} := \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{A^{n}}{n!}$$

converges for every $A \in M_{n} (\mathbb{C})$. However, some series might diverge for some matrices in $A \in M_{n} (\mathbb{C})$ (which I can't come up with an example right now).

I've looked up Wikipedia and it says :

[image]

in [this article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cayley%E2%80%93Hamilton_theorem), which basically means that every analytic function of a matrix can be evaluated as a finite-degree polynomial of the matrix. (Hence, it converges.) However, in [this article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analytic_function_of_a_matrix), it says :

[image]

which clearly states the condition for the power series to converge. Also, [in this article that is not that trustable](http://matrix.skku.ac.kr/nla/MatrixFt/MatrixFunction-2003.htm) (sorry, it's in Korean), it says that the power series converges only if every eigenvalue of $A$ is in the radius of convergence of the original power series. (In the complex plane if necessary.)

What is the correct answer? What is the 'radius of convergence' of a matrix power series? I'm very confused right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't understand what the Wikipedia article says. It says the IF the series $f(X)$ converges, THEN the limit is a polynomial in $X$. It doesn't always converge. For example, take $f(X) = \sum_{k \geqslant 0} X^k$ and $X = \lambda I_n$ a homethety, then $f(X) = \left(\sum_{k \geqslant 0} \lambda^k\right)I_n$ converges if and only if $|\lambda| < 1$.

What says you Korean article is almost right however. Let $(a_n)$ be a sequence of complex numbers and $R$ be its convergence radius. Let $X$ be an $n \times n$ matrix with complex coefficients and $\lambda_1,\ldots,\lambda_n$ be its eigenvalues counted with multiplicities and $\rho = \max\{|\lambda_k|\}$ be its spectral radius. You can prove that $\rho < R \Rightarrow f(X)$ converges $\Rightarrow \rho \leqslant R$ and the case $\rho = R$ is complicated, just like for classical complex series.

You can prove the second statement by contraposition. Let $v_i$ be a non zero vector such that $Xv_i = \lambda_iv_i$ with $|\lambda_i| > R$. Then $f(\lambda_i)$ diverges hence
$$
\left(\sum_{k = 0}^K a_kX^k\right)v_i = \left(\sum_{k = 0}^K a_k\lambda_i^k\right)v_i \textrm{ diverges when $K \rightarrow +\infty$},
$$
so $f(X)$ diverges.

For the first statement, begin by the simple case where $X = P^{-1}DP$ is diagonalisable. We have $D = \mathrm{diag}(\lambda_1,\ldots,\lambda_n)$ and,
\begin{align*}
\sum_{k = 0}^K a_kX^k & = \sum_{k = 0}^K a_kPD^kP^{-1}\\
& = P\left(\sum_{k = 0}^K a_k\mathrm{diag}(\lambda_1^k,\ldots,\lambda_n^k)\right)P^{-1}\\
& = P\mathrm{diag}\left(\sum_{k = 0}^K a_k\lambda_1^k,\ldots,\sum_{k = 0}^K a_k\lambda_n^k\right)P^{-1}\\
& \underset{K \rightarrow +\infty}{\longrightarrow} P\mathrm{diag}(f(\lambda_1),\ldots,f(\lambda_n))P,
\end{align*}
and this limit exists because each $\lambda_i$ verifies $|\lambda_i| \leqslant \rho < R$.

Now, in the general case, write $X = Y + N$ using Jordan-Chevalley decomposition ($Y$ is diagonalisable with the same eigenvalues as $X$ and $N$ is nilpotent, $Y$ and $N$ commute). $N$ is nilpotent thus $N^n = 0$ and the commutativity implies that we can use Newton binom formula to get that for all $k$,
$$
X^k = \sum_{i = 0}^k \binom{k}{i}N^iY^{k - i} = \sum_{i = 0}^n \binom{k}{i}N^iY^{k - i},
$$
with the convention $\binom{k}{i} = 0$ when $i > k$. Therefore, for all $K \geqslant n$,
\begin{align*}
\sum_{k = 0}^K a_kX^k & = \sum_{k = 0}^K a_k\sum_{i = 0}^n \binom{k}{i}N^iY^{k - i}\\
& = \sum_{i = 0}^n N^i\sum_{k = i}^K a_k\binom{k}{i}Y^{k - i}\\
& = \sum_{i = 0}^n N^i\sum_{k = 0}^{K - i} a_{k + i}\binom{k + i}{i}Y^k
\end{align*}
Now, let for all $i$, $f_i(x) = \sum_{k \geqslant 0} a_{k + i}\binom{k + i}{i}x^k$. $k \mapsto \binom{k + i}{i}$ is a polynomial in $k$ of degree $i$ hence it doesn't affect the radius of convergence of $f_i$, which equals $R$. By the first case ($Y$ is diagonalisable), $f_i(Y)$ exists and when $K \rightarrow +\infty$ in the previous equality, we obtain that $f(X)$ exists with,
$$
f(X) = \sum_{i = 0}^n N^if_i(Y) = \sum_{i = 0}^n N^i\sum_{k \geqslant 0} a_{k + i}\binom{k + i}{i}Y^k.
$$
It proves that $f$ is well defined on the open set $\{X \in \mathrm{Mat}_n(\mathbb{C})|\rho(X) < R\}$ and we probably have uniform convergence on all compact subsets, just like complex series.